# Как сделать чтобы этот скрипт работал ко всем классам?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы скрипт применялся ко всем `button` с классом `.linkinp`?
В моем коде около 50 `button`, но работает код работает только на первом.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var btn = document.querySelector('.linkinp ');
btn.onclick = function(e) {
  var element = document.querySelector(".doght-03");
  if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
   element.classList.remove("show-block");
  } else {
   element.classList.add("show-block");
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Зачем здесь jQuery если вы весь код написали на ES6?)
Кстате вместо 
if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
   element.classList.remove("show-block");
  } else {
   element.classList.add("show-block");
  }
можно написать
element.classList.toggle('show-block')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".linkinp").click(function() {
       var element = document.querySelector(".doght-03");
       if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
          element.classList.remove("show-block");
       } else {
          element.classList.add("show-block");
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает первый найденный элемент, чтобы найти все на странице, можно использовать [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), который вернет все найденные элементы.

Далее надо пробежаться по найденным элементам и назначить обработчик

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.linkinp');
btns.forEach(btn => btn.onclick = function(e) {
  var element = document.querySelector(".doght-03");
  if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
    element.classList.remove("show-block");
  } else {
    element.classList.add("show-block");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в первую очередь в задании переменной: var btn = document.**querySelector**('.linkinp ');
Нужно: **querySelectorAll**... Чтоб захватить **все** эл-ты класса linkinp...

ДАЛЕЕ! Прописываем цикл for на каждый элемент... Примерно так:

```js
document.addEventListener('domContentLoaded', function(){

var btn = document.querySelector**All**('.linkinp ');

for(let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var element = document.querySelector(".doght-03");
    if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
     element.classList.remove("show-block");
    } else {
     element.classList.add("show-block");
    }
  }
}
}
```

Написал версию без jQuery (на стандартном JS).

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // Аналог document.ready
  let link = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
  let block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  // Возвращают список элементов. 
  // Нужно пройтись по этому списку, чтобы достать каждый элемент
  
  for( let i = 0; i < link.length; i++ ){
    link[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      block[i].classList.toggle('show');
    });
  }  
});
```

```css
.link { display: block; margin: 5px; }

.block { display: none; border: 2px solid orange; margin: 5px; padding: 10px; }

.block.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<button class="link">111</button>
<div class="block">111</div>

<button class="link">222</button>
<div class="block">222</div>

<button class="link">333</button>
<div class="block">333</div>
```

На jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.link').on('click', function(){
    var index = $('.link').index( $(this) );
    $('.block').eq(index).toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.link { display: block; margin: 5px; }

.block { display: none; border: 2px solid orange; margin: 5px; padding: 10px; }

.block.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="link">111</button>
<div class="block">111</div>

<button class="link">222</button>
<div class="block">222</div>

<button class="link">333</button>
<div class="block">333</div>
```